# Delegate method is not being called

Tags: swift, ios10, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a splitview controller and the Master view has a button (Note) that pushes the Note view onto the Detail view. The Detail view makes used of navigation controller to help users navigate back and forth among multiple view controllers. Inside those view controllers, I have delegate methods that pushes Note view onto itself. This is what my UI look like :

[image]

[image]

The Note button works as I expected when the app is initially run. It still works when I tap one of the list elments and traverse to the views at the deeper level. However, it stops working when I go back to the very first view (which was working initially). I'm not sure what is causing this inconsistent behaviour and I appreciate much if you guys could help me figure this out.

This is excerpt of my code :

**Master View**

```
protocol ChildViewDelegate: class {
   func updateView()
   func pushOntoDetailViewNaviController(_ viewName: String)
}

class MasterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {
   ....
   @IBAction func noteTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       pushOntoActiveNaviController("NoteGalleryView")
    }

   private func pushOntoActiveNaviController(_ viewName: String) {

       guard let splitView = self.splitViewController else {
          return
       }

       if splitView.viewControllers.count > 1 {
          // Push view onto any active detailed view
          self.delegate?.pushOntoDetailViewNaviController(viewName)
       } else { //If active view is the master view (true for iphone), then push it onto the master view
          if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewName) {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
          }
       }


   }
   ....
}
```

**Detail View**

```
class DetailTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, GADBannerViewDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    masterViewController = (self.splitViewController?.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? MasterViewController
    masterViewController?.delegate = self

}

extension DetailTableViewController: ChildViewDelegate {

   func updateUI() {
     ....
   }

   func updateView() {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
           self.updateUI()

       }

   }

   func pushOntoDetailViewNaviController(_ viewName: String) {
       if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewName) {
           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody has the same issue, it's because I'm setting delegate variable inside viewDidLoad which is invoked when view is initially loaded. It isn't invoked when view appears again when user navigates back to the view from deeper view controllers. The delegate variable should have been set inside viewWillAppear.